# How to make animations only work for certain values?

Tags: css, vue.js, animation, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind and I have a div with these classes `fixed top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2`.

I'm trying to make an animation that starts from `opacity: 0; translate: scale(0.5);`
and ends at the defaults which are  `opacity: 1; translate: scale(1);`

Currently, it animates the `translate-y` and `translate-x` from tailwind classes.
Is there a way to make it only animate the `scale()` of the element?

EDIT:
Full component:

```
<template>
    <transition name="AddTask">
        <div class="fixed left-0 right-0 top-0 bottom-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-slate-500 w-5/6 h-4/5 z-10 rounded-xl" v-if="$store.state.AddTaskShown">
            <div class="m-4">
                <h1 class="text-3xl mb-4">Add New Task</h1>
                <label>
                    Task Name:
                    <input placeholder="Name" type="text" class="block my-5 w-full mx-auto border-slate-600 bg-slate-500 outline-none border-b-2">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="Description" type="text" class="block my-5 w-full mx-auto border-slate-600 bg-slate-500 outline-none border-b-2">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="Date" type="date" class="block my-5 w-full mx-auto border-slate-600 bg-slate-500 outline-none border-b-2"> 
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style scoped>
.AddTask-enter-from{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
.AddTask-enter-to{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.AddTask-enter-active{
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Does the transition-property help you? See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property#customizing-your-theme

Comment: @Christian nope, it does basically the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do that - not because of tailwind but because of css. you can only apply transition to properties, not property values.

there's a way you can go around this with flexbox. just create a wrapper div for it.

```
<div class="fixed left-0 right-0 top-0 bottom-0 flex items-center justify-center">
   <!-- div with animation here -->
</div>
```

Comment: This did work, but the element isn't centered anymore.

Comment: may i know what classes have you applied to this child div?

Comment: I only applied m-4

Comment: huh? that's weird. for me it's works. it would be nice if you send me how the whole component looks.

Comment: I edited it, take a look at it

Comment: ok i found it, remove the "w-5/6 h-4/5" properties from the parent div (i think you wanted to use them in a child component) left-0 right-0 top-0 bottom-0 will be the entire screen